# kinetic.js drag and drop doesn't work unless I enable it for the entire stage

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

When setting `draggable` to `true` for the objects, they aren't draggable unless I also enable it for the stage. This is however very undesired in my application; i want only some particular objects to be draggable.

```
function initGUI()
{
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage(
    {
        container: 'stage',
        width: w.innerWidth,
        height: w.innerHeight,
        // draggable: true // Uncommenting this makes everything draggable
    });

    layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var debugRect = new Kinetic.Rect(
    {
        fill: 'green',
        x: 0,
        y: 0, 
        draggable: true, // This isn't draggable despite this line
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    })
    layer.add(debugRect);
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div id="stage"></div>
</body>
```

I've used Kinetic for some applications before but never encountered this.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look.Its Working!
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shirgavetushar/ktak9oms/)

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 500
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
 stage.add(layer);

  var debugRect = new Kinetic.Rect(
{
    fill: 'green',
    x: 0,
    y: 0, 
    draggable: true, // This isn't draggable despite this line
    width: 200,
    height: 200
})
layer.add(debugRect);
layer.draw();
```